# What are the differences between using an HTML5 embedded video vs. an iframe with a YouTube link?

Tags: html, video, iframe, html5-video

I'm debating whether or not to store a video on my server and call it through an HTML5 tag, or upload the video onto YouTube and use an iframe to embed the YouTube link. I'm not sure which would work more efficiently, or the differences between each one. What are the differences between using a HTML5 video tag and using a YouTube link and iframe tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Using a self-hosted video with HTML5**

Advantages:

1. Full Control over markup and interface

Disadvantages:

1. Browser support is in your hands
2. Video download will be slower on your server as compared to YouTube

Recommended Usage:

Use a javascript plugin like https://plyr.io/ which will help with cross-browser and responsive concerns. Serve the video from a CDN if possible

**Youtube Hosted**

Advantages:

1. Performant
2. Browser support is everything

Disadvantages:

1. YouTube branded by default
2. Little control over the interface

Recommended Usage:
Use iframe embed code provided by youtube. For responsive assistance, see http://embedresponsively.com/. Also plyr.io allows you to play YouTube videos.

Answer (score 0):

For my experience with `<iframe>` and `<video>` tags:

I found an issue with the `<iframe>` tag when you want to do an autoplay for your video while using a mobile or tablet device with "Chrome" & "Apple".

In my case, I used to do a click function to play video, that's what is impossible with `<iframe>` tag, so I use the `<video>` tag to resolve the issue.